# Spring MVC (Mapping)

Tags: spring-mvc

Здравствуйте.
Нужна помощь, подсказка =)

Система отчетов.
Задача, есть несколько подразделений, в каждом подразделении можно получить 5 отчетов. 
Необходимо вот что, изначально человек попадает на страницу `/reports` и видит перед собой форму в которой может выбрать подразделение, и вид отчета.
После отправки формы хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы адрес в адресной строке менялся на `/reports/{подразделение}/{выбранный отчет}` и соответствующая вьюха показывала пользователю выбранный отчет.

Как вот такой редирект организовать?

Правильно мыслю, что у нас должен быть контроллер с маппингом который обрабатывает информация от формы, после чего перенаправляет дальше (на другой контроллер с передачей информации которая необходима для генерации отчета?, или можно сразу как то изменить юрл, передать данные, обработать и вывести? Надо использовать несколько контроллеров или достаточно одного двух?

P.S для того чтобы отчет сформировался, необходимо передать в запрос три параметра, подразделение, начальную и конечную дату.

пока писал появилась мысль добавлять в uri редиректа ссылку с параметрами, но насколько я понимаю тогда потеряется ЧПУ.

Comment: А зачем делать редирект? Можно же из формы сформировать ссылку JS-ом на `/reports/{подразделение}/{выбранный отчет}` и на сервере обрабатывать ее (добавьте код формы). И что за потеря ЧПУ?

Comment: про чпу это я перемудрил , на это можно не обращать внимание =) по поводу js не задумывался, вполне подходит как вариант...но что делат ь в случаи отключения джава скрипта?

Comment: редирект понадобится во первых если все таки отключеный скрипты  и во вторых для того, чтобы у пользователя адресная строка менялась по запросу отчета

Comment: да, еще деталь помимо 4 спринга, используется и thymelea. в его документации тоже есть упоминание про Building URIs to controllers с отсылкой на документацию по спрингу..но скудное объяснение

Answer (score 2):

Метод, который получает данные постом с формы и потом редиректит:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "reports", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String get2(@RequestParam("param1") String param1,
                   @RequestParam("param2") String param2,
                   @RequestParam("param3") String param3,
                   @RequestParam("param4") String param4,
                   RedirectAttributes attributes) {
    attributes.addFlashAttribute("param3", param3);
    attributes.addFlashAttribute("param4", param4);
    System.out.println("Редирект с " + param1 + "," + param2 + "," + param3 + "," + param4);
    return "redirect:/reports/" + param1 + "/" + param2;
}
```

Это вызывается после редиректа и отправляет страницу report:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "reports/{param1}/{param2}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String get3(@PathVariable String param1,
                   @PathVariable String param2,
                   Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    //todo тут может быть NPE, если пользователь обновит страницу, добавить обработчик
    String param3 = (String) model.asMap().get("param3"); //первый способ
    Map<String, ?> flashMap = RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(request);
    String param4 =  (String) flashMap.get("param4"); //второй способ
    System.out.println("Сделать что-то с " + param1 + "," + param2 + "," + param3 + "," + param4);
    return "reports";
}
```

В этом методе 2 способа получения параметров и если пользователь обновит страницу, то может возникнуть NPE, и нужно ее обработать. Насколько это правильно не знаю, но работает.

Форма на странице из предыдущего ответа:

```
<form action="/reports" method="post">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="param1" value="Mickey"><br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="param2" value="Mouse"><br>
    Second name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="param3" value="third"><br>
    My name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="param4" value="param4Value"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Пример реализован [отсюда](http://javainsimpleway.com/spring-mvc-redirecting-model-attributes-from-one-controller-to-other-controller/)

Comment: еще подсказка нужна, из формы прилетает объект(модель, как того просит thymeleaf). В модели четыре поля, необходимые для построения отчета, тип отчета, подразделение, начальная и конечная дата для выборки, соответственно в модели есть геттеры и сеттеры к этим данным. Если использовать редирект, могу сформировать url извлекая подразделение и тип отчета, но если передавать данные дальше у нас получается ссылка вида {reports/???????/category?sDate=2016-08-02&lDate=2016-10-24} можно ли как то спрятать дату выборки от пользователя?

Comment: Дату выборки боюсь не спрятать. Можете попробовать сохранить в сессии эти параметры, и после редиректа достать, удалить из сессии и сделать что нужно пользователю. Ну а так не вижу смысла скрывать дату(т.е. валидную ссылку) от пользователя.

Comment: я Вас понял, спасиб за подсказки

Comment: получается нет возможности вместе с редиректом, передавать  скрытые параметры. что делает  forward:  ?

Comment: `forward` это серверный редирект, пользователь просто не увидит откуда взята страница и ссылка останется `/reports` в браузере, как и при обычном пост запросе. Добавил вариант как описали, но могут возникать ошибки в приложении, Вам нужно будет их обработать, пометка в коде есть.

Answer (score 0):

используйте обычный html тег [form](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp), прик клике на кнопку откроется страница с GET парметраметрами из формы, например `/reports?param1=aaa&param2=bbb&param3=ccc` на мапенге нужен 1 контролер (/reports), который из `request` получит GET параметры и отобразит на странице содержимое. пример формы:

```
<form action="/reports/">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="param1" value="Mickey"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="param2" value="Mouse"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: разьве в таком случаи у нас uri в адресной строке не останется /reports?   Сейчас данные с формы не проблема получить, но надо сделать так чтобы после отправки формы в адресной строке пользователя отображалось именно /reports/{подразделение}/{выбранный отчет} . Спринг 4 версии , и то , что мне нужно похожу на то, что в документации называется Building URIs ..только мне не совсем до конца понятно как это работает

Comment: тогда только редиректом, форму делаете через POST, мапите один контролер на `/reports` с методом POST, с которого перенаправляете на свой /reports/{подразделение}/{выбранный отчет}

Comment: перенаправляю, вопрос сообственно как вместе с редиректом передать данные с формы =)

Comment: варианта 2, либо результат записать в сессию, но тогда отчет будет доступен только тем кто перешел на страницу с формы `request.getSession().setAttribute(" /reports/{подразделение}/{выбранный отчет}",report);`, второй вариант писать все отчеты в бд, тогда они будут доступны без формы.

Comment: так выборка и так идет из бд, смысл их переписывать? мне кажется MrFylypenko близок к тому , что мне нужно или даже попал в цель, сейчас реализую, как появится время, проверю и отпишусь